# Let $x,y \in X$, $X$ topological vector space then there are two neighborhoods $V_x,V_y$ such that $V_x + V_y \subset W$

Tags: proof-verification, topological-vector-spaces

I wish to prove that in a tvs for any $x,y$ and $W$ neighborhood of $x+y$ there a two neighborhoods $V_x,V_y$ such that

$$
V_x+V_y \subset W,
$$

the proof should be simple because if this weren't the case then I could build a convergent sequence $a_j+b_j \in X- W$ (which is closed) such that $a_j+b_j \to x+y$, but this would imply $x+y\in X - W$ which is closed, hence a contradiction, is this correct?

(I assume a similar argument could be applied for the scalar multiplcation, is this correct?)

Thank you

Comment: This is one of the axioms of a topological vector space, i.e. the continuity of the addition...

Comment: Confused by notation $W $ and $V$.

Comment: The axioms are $+$ and $*$ are continuous,  not the property mentioned above, that should be a consequence of continuity.

Comment: Yes, and if you unpack what continuity means, that is precisely the definition, once you remember how you construct the product topology...

Comment: @Bob, I'm asking this because my reference doesn't mention product topology at all (Rudin, Functional Analysis).

Comment: @MichaelBurr, isn't "radius" related to "metric"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $W$ is neighborhood of $x+y$ and since $+$ is continuoues, there is a neighborhoods $W^\star$ if $(x,y)$ such that$$(\forall (x',y')\in W^\star):x'+y'\in W.\tag1$$And since we're dealing with the product topology here, there are neighborhoods $V_x$ and $V_y$ of $x$ and $y$ respectively such that $V_x\times V_y\subset W^\star$. But then $(1)$ implies that $V_x+V_y\subset W$, because if $x'\in V_x$ and $y'\in V_y$, then $(x',y')\in V_x\times V_y\subset W^\star$ and therefore $x'+y'\in W$.

Comment: The very last line is what puzzles me, can you please expound that?

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: I was about to write a comment with that explanation, but out of curiosity was my first argument correct?

Comment: Your proof assumes that $W$ is open, but that's not a serious problem, since every neghborhood contains an open neighborhood. But it also assumes that your space is first countable, and that's a serious problem.

Comment: Fair point, thank you!